# How to switch between terminals in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce4-terminal

How does one effectively switch between terminals in Xubuntu. 
I tried using Alt + Tilde(~) but it doesn't work. Also Alt + $(Tab number) doesn't work and results in an operation in terminal 
(Arg: 2)

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the solution.
You just type in <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys for it to work.